# Can a program output to STDERR and still return a zero exit status?

Tags: linux, process, stdout, exit-status, stderr

I'm working on refactoring some Python scripts intended to be run from the command line. The scripts use logging, which makes some messages be written to STDERR (among other things). I wonder if it's appropriate for a program in Linux to output to STDERR, but still return a zero (success) exit status. I thought that STDERR should only be consulted if the exit status is non-zero.

P.S. Basically I need to capture the output from the scripts, and send it to another service for processing, along with the exit status. I want the data to be consistent.

Comment: Not sure about _the_ answer (there is currently a close vote as opinion-based and I agree that, to some extent, "it depends"), but here are a couple of thoughts: the `read` builtin (at least in Bash, dash, ksh) writes its optional message to the user to standard error, a not-uncommon way to talk to the user in interactive scripts, and nevertheless returns `0` on success; `ssh -v` writes debugging information on standard error and still returns `0` on success.

Comment: POSIX `dd` [is *obliged* to use stderr on completion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html#tag_20_31_11), regardless of its exit status.

Comment: Your question title asks if a program _can_ do that, and the question itself asks if it's _appropriate_. Those aren't exactly the same, and the first is completely an objective technical question (yeah, sure it's possible) while the second seems a bit more preference-based (who gets to call what's appropriate?).

Comment: …  And I don’t understand what your second paragraph (“P.S.”) has to do with either the first paragraph or the title.  Are you asking about a generic program (which we might call a ‘‘child process’’) or a wrapper / controller / supervisor program that runs subordinate programs (so *it* is a parent process)?  If it’s the latter, then, again, the answer is “it depends”.  Are you concerned only about success or failure of the child, from a bird’s eye view — i.e., is it safe to proceed with subsequent commands?  — or are you concerned about anomalies, which you might want to pass along to a human?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I was talking about interpreting the results (output to stderr and exit status) together. AFAIR, it was a parent Python process calling subprograms.

Comment: I have posted my thoughts as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, programs can output to standard error and still return a zero exit status. You will find many POSIX utilities specifications which state that "The standard error shall be used only for **diagnostic** messages."

A clear example of a program that outputs to STDERR and returns 0 is [`crontab`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/crontab.html). Try

```
EDITOR=nano crontab -e 2> stderr.out; echo $?
```

Do not modify the cron file and exit the editor. `0` will be echoed and yet there will be some message in `stderr.out`, such as (in my case)

```
no crontab for user - using an empty one
No modification made
```

Answer (score 4):

`stderr` is just a predefined stream with file number `2`. 
The convention is to print there important or alternative information
(it does not have to be an error).

For example, `curl` will by default output the messages triggered by `--verbose` to `stderr` because `stdout` is already being used to get the actual result. So you will have a zero exit code and output to `stderr`:

```
$ curl ifconfig.me

$ curl --verbose ifconfig.me 2>messages.txt
```

The exit code, on the other hand, is the parameter of `sys.exit()`
(see [_exit(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/exit.2.html) and [exit(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html)).  There is no rule linking the two. 
Take [`grep`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html), for example; that will output to `stderr` in case of error but may adjust the exit code depending on the flags.

> Normally the exit status is 0 if a line is selected,
> 1 if no lines were selected, and 2 if an error occurred. 
> However, if the **`-q`** or **`--quiet`** or
> **`--silent`** is used and a line is selected,
> the exit status is 0  even  if
> an error occurred.

Comment: @ilkkachu the user specifically said "I'm working on refactoring some Python scripts". That's the reason I added the "pythonism" to answer. I understand we try to keep the answers general, but in this case it might make sense to explain it from the perspective of the language being used.

Comment: ah heck, I'm not sure how I missed that mention reading the question. I blame it on the late hour, sorry. :(

Answer (score 2):

Well, I’m still not clear what this question is asking. 
But, since it has been reopened, I’ll post what I said earlier. 
At the risk of repeating what others (and I) have said:

1. It is certainly possible for a program to write to stderr
   and still exit with a status of 0. 
   While it is unusual, it is not considered bad practice.
2. If your primary concern is whether it is appropriate / safe
   to run program *N+1* after program *N* (and possibly other predecessor tasks)
   have exited,
   you should probably make that decision based on exit status alone.
3. If you want to escalate anomalies to the attention of a human,
   and they aren’t already being logged adequately,
   *then* you should look at stderr.